# Is there a Rhythmbox plugin to listen to music from YouTube?

Tags: rhythmbox

Is anyone aware of a plugin for Rhythmbox to stream music directly from YouTube?

Comment: Try here, in this list:  https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Rhythmbox/Plugins/ThirdParty (Assuming that you use Gnome).

Comment: That plugin searches yt based on a  song selected from your library

Comment: Thank you! I installed and enabled the plugin but don't see any new entry to search YouTube. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/WIeIUPF.png)